# SharpCompress unpacking locks files

Tags: c#, locking

Im trying to make a process where I unpack a set of rar-files using SharpCompress and then delete them.

I first have a foreach loop which loops over the different set of files to be unpacked like this:

```
foreach (var package in extractionPackages.Where(package => Extractor.ExtractToFolder(package, destinationFolder)))
        {
            FileHelper.DeleteExtractionFiles(package);
        }
```

The extraction process is taken straight of the SharpCompress Tests code and goes like this:

```
public static bool ExtractToFolder(ExtractionPackage extractionPackage, string extractionPath)
    {
        var fullExtractionPath = Path.Combine(extractionPath, extractionPackage.FolderName);
        try
        {
            using (var reader = RarReader.Open(extractionPackage.ExtractionFiles.Select(p => File.OpenRead(p.FullPath))))
            {
                while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
                {
                    reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(fullExtractionPath, ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the first code block I then call to delete the files but there I recieve an error due to that the files are locked by another process:
**The process cannot access the file 'file.rar' because it is being used by another process.**

If I try to put the deletion after the foreach-loop I am able to delete all but the last set of files if there are more than one. If it is just one the same issue occurs since the last set of files doesn't seems to be "unlocked".

How can I structure the code so that the files is unlocked?

Comment: `File.OpenRead(p.FullPath)` is opening files but not closing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using an example from Nunrar and modifying it a bit I finally seems to have solved the issue:

```
public static bool ExtractToFolder(ExtractionPackage extractionPackage, string extractionPath)
    {
        var fullExtractionPath = Path.Combine(extractionPath, extractionPackage.FolderName);

        try
        {
            using (var reader = RarReader.Open(GetStreams(extractionPackage)))//extractionPackage.ExtractionFiles.Select(p => File.OpenRead(p.FullPath)), Options.None))
            {
                while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
                {
                    reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(fullExtractionPath, ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Stream> GetStreams(ExtractionPackage package)
    {
        foreach (var item in package.ExtractionFiles)
        {
            using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(item.FullPath))
            {
                yield return input;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Wrapping the Stream input return with using() fixed a problem that I had with trying to unrar from a removable USB drive

Answer (score 0):

By default (and probably a flaw) is that I leave the Streams open as I did not create them myself.  However, the .NET framework usually breaks this rule with things like StreamReader etc. so it's expected that they'd be closed.

I'm thinking I'm going to change this behavior.  In the meantime, you ought to be able to fix this yourself by calling this:

```
RarReader.Open(extractionPackage.ExtractionFiles.Select(p => File.OpenRead(p.FullPath)), Options.None)
```

Comment: My rule is: If you didn't create it, you dont destroy it. I dont think it is a flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble. I used SharpCompress for adding files in archive and I need to delete files after archiving. I had tried wrap streams with using() {} - but this solution didn't worked in my case. When I added to my code Application.DoEvents() - it solved the problem.